# How to use the return callback object from express in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, express

All:

> **[UPDATE]** I figure it out, it turns out that:

```
        $http({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/users",
            method: "JSONP",
            params: {
                callback:"JSON_CALLBACK", // need to be this name

                q: $scope.qs
            }
        })
        .success(function( data ){   
            console.log("return data length:",data.length);
            if(data.length>0){
                $scope.cdata = data;
            }
        })
```

==========================================================
I am new to ExpressJS and AngularJS, right now, I m trying to use Express to build a REST JSONP service to provide data.

And when I try Angular in the frontend like:

```
            $scope.qs = 0;

            $http({
                url: "http://localhost:3000/users",
                method: "JSONP",
                params: {
                    callback:"dataservice",
                    q: $scope.qs
                }
            })
            .success(function(err, data){  
                console.log("return data length:",data.length);
                if(data.length>0){
                    $scope.cdata = data;
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, err){
                console.log(data, err);
            });
        };
```

Annd on server side I use:

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var jsonp = req.query.callback;
    var start = parseInt(req.query.q);
    var retdata = [];


    if( !isNaN(start) ){
        retdata = cdata.slice(start);
    }
    if(jsonp){
        console.log("I return as JSONP");
        res.jsonp( retdata );
    }else {
        console.log("I return as JSON");
        res.json( retdata );
    }
});
```

From chrome console, I can see the return JSONP response is like:

```
/**/ typeof dataservice === 'function' && dataservice([{"Name":"Island Trading","City":"Cowes","Country":"UK"},{"Name":"Königlich Essen","City":"Brandenburg","Country":"Germany"},{"Name":"Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars","City":"Vancouver","Country":"Canada"},{"Name":"Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti","City":"Bergamo","Country":"Italy"},{"Name":"North/South","City":"London","Country":"UK"},{"Name":"Paris spécialités","City":"Paris","Country":"France"},{"Name":"Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery","City":"Albuquerque","Country":"USA"},{"Name":"Simons bistro","City":"København","Country":"Denmark"},{"Name":"The Big Cheese","City":"Portland","Country":"USA"},{"Name":"Vaffeljernet","City":"Århus","Country":"Denmark"},{"Name":"Wolski Zajazd","City":"Warszawa","Country":"Poland"}]);
```

But Angular can not use it in .successs, but trigger the .error handler.

I wonder if anyone can help me with this? How to use the return response

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, you are sending the callback so that is what you have to call to retrieve the data:

```
function userCallback(data) {
    console.log("return data length:",data.length);
    if(data.length>0){
        $scope.cdata = data;
    }
}

$http({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/users",
    method: "JSONP",
    params: {
        callback: userCallback,
        q: $scope.qs
    }
}).then(userCallback);
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not work.  ERROR:Uncaught ReferenceError: functionuserCallbackdataconsole is not defined

Comment: NVM, I figure it out myself, it turns out the callback name need to be JSON_CALLBACK